# Derivative of $h(t,x)=x\cdot x=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$

Tags: systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose that $x'=A(t)x=-A(t)^{T}x$, where $A(t)$ is a matricial function. What is the derivative of $h(t,x)=x\cdot x=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$. I'm trying to prove that it is $0$, this way $h$ is a first integral for the system.

**Attempt:** The derivative of $h$ is $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(t,x)x'+\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t,x)=2x \cdot Ax + 0 \neq 0 $$ what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The matrix $A(t) $ is skew-symmetric, so $x \cdot A(t) x=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Desperado Oh I see thanks $<x,Ax>=0$ for all $x$, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear: since $x^T Ax\in \mathbb R$ it holds  $x^T Ax=(x^T Ax)^T= x^T A^Tx= -x^T Ax$, hence  $x^T Ax=0$.

Comment: Do you now if Is it valid say $(x\cdot x)'=2x$?

Comment: @apa, I don't think so, $x\cdot x$ is a scalar function, and $2x$ not.

Comment: @apa Correct is: $\nabla h(x)= 2 x$.